# everything except of this

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to program a Discord bot currency system and I try to save the data in a .json file and I ran into the problem. If I use the `fs.readFilSync(<filename>)` command I replace the whole file so I tried to take the part that I want to edit and take the part before the replace without the part I want to edit.

The JSON file is supposed to look like this:

```
{ <userid>: <currency>, <userid>: <currency>, <userid>: <currency>, ...}
```

And what I tried to program so it looks like this is this:

```
    const fs = require('fs');
    const mA = message.author.id;
    const currency = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('<filename>.json'));
    
    let a = message.author.id
    
    

    var sampleObject = {[mA] : currency[a] + 1,}, !currency[a] // !! here is the problem!!
    
    fs.writeFile("<filname>.json", JSON.stringify(sampleObject, null, 4), (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err); return};
        
            message.channel.send(`add +1 point now you got ${currency[a] + 1} points`)
    });
```

where I wrote "// !! here is the problem!!" is the problem I tried to negate there to say everything except of this. My question is, is there a way to say everything except of this.

Comment: "{[mA] : currency[a] + 1,}, !currency[a]" This syntax is not valid. I don't understand what you really need.

Comment: Please explain in more detail exactly what you want, and what exactly the problem is. This question is incredibly difficult to understand. What is the intended behavior of your code, and what is it actually doing? What is the problem? And what do you mean by "negate there to say everything except of this"? If you mean you want to edit just one key-value pair in a JSON file, just do `currency[a] += 1` (or whatever number you want to add by), and then `fs.writeFileSync("filename.json", JSON.stringify(currency, null, 4))`.

Comment: Looks like you are overcomplicating a simple task. Just do: `currency[mA] = currency[mA]+1` or `currency[mA]++` then save it.

Comment: I want to say everything except of this. As an example u have a list of things u have to buy and u want copy the list without one part and i want to know if there is a way how to say everything except of this part.

Comment: I think the your data is an array, not an oject. `{ <userid>: <currency>, <userid>: <currency>, <userid>: <currency>, ...}`. If this is the case update your question: `[{ <userid>: <currency>},{ <userid>: <currency>}, {<userid>: <currency>}, ...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, assuming I understood your problem correctly, you simply need to get the current contents of the JSON file, parse it into an object literal, modify just the value you want to modify, and then save the newly modified object. Here is an example:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
let currency = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("filename.json"));

//Example - Add 2 to the message author's currency:
currency[message.author.id] += 2;

//Example - Subtract 1 from the message author's currency:
currency[message.author.id] -= 1;

//You can do the same with multiplication (`*=`), division (`/=`), and mod (`%=`)

fs.writeFileSync("filename.json", JSON.stringify(currency, null, 4));
```

In the future, you really need to be more detailed and precise about what your problem is, what you want, etc. in your questions. It was very difficult to understand what you wanted from your question and the weird, incorrect "negation" syntax.

Comment: if i try this i get the error: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView

Comment: And i want to apologize for my not valid syntax.

Comment: be sure you changed 'filename.json' with your actual file path, and if your problem got fixed and you get a new different one, just accept this answer a create a new question ^^

Comment: @3IsAGoodNumber I forgot to `JSON.stringify()` the `currency` object before writing it to the JSON file, which was causing that error for you. I've edited the answer, it should be working now.